# "Loviest-doviest" or "lovey-doviest"?

Tags: idioms, word-usage

I know that this term in its comparative form would 'lovier-dovier', but somehow I can't decide whether it is "loviest-doviest" or "lovey-doviest" Which is the correct form?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't remember if I've ever heard 'lovey-dovey' used comparatively, but the 'lovey-dovier' form sounds more correct to my ear, making me think that 'lovey-doviest' would be the best superlative form.

'lovier-dovier' seems like a comic exaggeration of an already comical phrase, to say that the parties are more loving and coo more like doves than a contending couple, to emphasize that they win against the other pair on all dimensions.

For 'loviest-doviest' I guess that would mean that they outrank all possible contenders on both the lovey and dovey dimensions.

Is there a distributive law for the application of -er in English? This comic application of -er is acting like distribution of multiplication over sums in mathematics.